# Entity Framework defining one ForeignKey to several entities 1 to 1..0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys, one-to-one

I have 3 entities which one of them has one FK to another ones (optional)

```
class Person
{
   public int id {get;set;}

   public int? logid {get;set;}
   [ForeignKey("logid")
   public TaskLog Log{get;set;}
}

class Product
{
   public int id {get;set;}

   public int? logid {get;set;}
   [ForeignKey("logid")
   public TaskLog Log{get;set;}
}

class TaskLog
{
   public int id {get;set;}
   public int? refid {get;set;} //will be fk for Person and Product
   public Person Person {get;set;}
   public Product Product {get;set;}
}
```

and some FluentApi for cascading and relation

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TaskLog>()
            .HasOptional(i => i.Person).WithMany().HasForeignKey(i => i.refid).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
            .HasOptional(i => i.TaskLog).WithMany().HasForeignKey(i => i.logid).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<TaskLog>()
            .HasOptional(i => i.Product).WithMany().HasForeignKey(i => i.refid).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
            .HasOptional(i => i.TaskLog).WithMany().HasForeignKey(i => i.logid).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

The above entities has migrated to database correctly without any additional fields.

But the problem is that when I want to create new `TaskLog` for an existing `Person`:

```
var person = PersonManager.loadById(1);
person.Log = new TaskLog() { ... };
personManager.SaveChanges();
```

the following error occurred that means it look inside `Product` for same id (same as person id) and because there isn't any product so it couldn't add new TaskLog, because it has optional relation to Product as well.

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.TaskLog_dbo.Product_refid".
>   The conflict occurred in database "database1", table "dbo.Product", column 'id'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

So I want have a field in the TaskLog entity which will using as reference for both Product and Person (and more) but not together.

One TaskLog might be for one Person or might be for one Product or non of them but not for both of them together.

<del>Please note that I want to have that refid and I know could using InverseProperty and removing refid from TaskLog.</del>
**EDIT :**
Please post solution without `refid` if you are sure that `refid` is problem and you can solve the above relationship without additional field in `TaskLog`.
**Solution for a 1 to 1..0 relationship between `Person-TaskLog` and also `Product-TaskLog` by one FK in TaskLog or without any additional field in TaskLog**

Comment: Are you sure such approach should work? I would suggest to make 2 separate fields as foreign keys for person and product.

Comment: It is not good solution adding FK per each entity because there are more than 5 entities which will related to TaskLog. If you have solution without refid , I can ignore it.

Comment: I want to have access to Person or Product from `TaskLog` and also access to `TaskLog` from Person and Product, without declaring separate fields to Product and Person in `TaskLog` because there are several entities like them which should will assigned to `TaskLog`

Answer (score 0):

Sql Server actually allows creating foreign keys by which one database field refers to two primary keys. This is part of the database create script:

```sql
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TaskLogs] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.TaskLogs_dbo.People_refid]
    FOREIGN KEY ([refid]) REFERENCES [dbo].[People] ([id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TaskLogs] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.TaskLogs_dbo.Products_refid]
    FOREIGN KEY ([refid]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Products] ([id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

So `refid` both points to `People` and `Products`. Well, there's only one way to satisfy both FK constraints: adding a `TaskLog` with a `refid` that corresponds with a `Person` *and* a `Product`.

For the new `TaskLog` you only have a `Person`, not a `Product`, hence the FK violation. And *if* you also had a matching `Product`, both the `Person` and the `product` would both have to have the same `TaskLog`. Is that really what you want?

If not, you can keep insisting on a solution with only one `refid` but it's simply not possible.

Comment: No, I don't and as you say there is not any simple solution by one `refid` so I add one additional field to `TaskLog` which is `discriminator` and by both `refid` and `discriminator` I reached relation between `TaskLog` to several entities and also relation between other entities to `TaskLog`

Comment: Then you have what's called *polymorphic associations* without a hard foreign key in the database.